# Adding files to an IzPack .jar installer

Tags: java, installation, izpack

I need to modify an installation package produced with [IzPack](http://izpack.org/) 5.1.3.

In practice I have to update some files present in the installation package.

The package was not produced by me and therefore I don't have the original files to rebuild it.

I know that in the installer there is a Pack of IzPack, I would like to open this pack (it's a compressed file of some kind) and replace/add files to it.

I think I should use [PackFile](https://github.com/izpack/izpack/blob/master/izpack-api/src/main/java/com/izforge/izpack/api/data/PackFile.java), [PackInfo](https://github.com/izpack/izpack/blob/master/izpack-api/src/main/java/com/izforge/izpack/api/data/PackInfo.java), [Unpacker](https://github.com/izpack/izpack/blob/master/izpack-installer/src/main/java/com/izforge/izpack/installer/unpacker/Unpacker.java) and [DefaultFileUnpacker](https://github.com/izpack/izpack/blob/master/izpack-installer/src/main/java/com/izforge/izpack/installer/unpacker/DefaultFileUnpacker.java) classes by IzPack, but I have no idea if it's feasible, nor how to proceed.

Here are a couple of image of what it is inside that .jar installer
[image: this is the content of /resources diurectory inside the .jar installer]

[image: this the pack file]

Comment: Not currently, but I've made some progress using the DefaultFileUnpacker class

Comment: can you edit it to on your question?